# "Battery not present" but it is [13.10]

Tags: 13.10, battery

In 12.04 and Windows 8 it recognized the battery just fine.I think it's this version of Ubuntu (13.10) that has the problem.I haven't istalled any updates.Do you think that might be the problem? Should I upgrade to 14.04 and see if it solves it?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 is end of life, so this question is technically off-topic.  Yes, you should upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to 14.04 and see if your battery is still supported by default. If it doesn't work, why not stick with 12.04 (which you know works) and still has a few years of support left?